# Django-admin starproject throws syntaxerror

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Im using python 3.5 and django 1.8.6 but whenever i call the django-admin startproject, it throws the syntax error, even when i call it in comand line. I dont know how to fix it. Please help me.

```
import django
>>> print (django.get_version())
1.8.6
>>> django-admin startproject mydite
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to run this from the command line, not from inside Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir django_project
cd django_project
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install django
#Then run 
django-admin startproject mydite
```

If you have any questions go through
[this link](https://realpython.com/learn/start-django/)